# Is there a built-in function returning number of inserted or updated or deleted records?

Tags: mysql

If the insert or update or delete statement is dynamic or based on a select statement so that the number of rows inserted or updated or deleted is not known in advance , is there a built-in function returning that number ?

Comment: Do you mean a SQL function, or a method within your local friendly programming language (such as PHP, or Perl, C#, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_affected_rows()` may be called immediately after executing a statement with `mysql_query()` or `mysql_real_query()`. It returns the number of rows changed, deleted, or inserted by the last statement if it was an `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `INSERT`. For `SELECT` statements, `mysql_affected_rows()` works like `mysql_num_rows()`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html

Answer (score 1):

in php can get affectedrecord

```
mysql_query('DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id < 10');
printf("Records deleted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Use:

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

Post you insert/delete/.. a row.

Answer (score 0):

In Java or any other language that provides an interface for a database, the insert and update functions return the number of rows updated in the table.

Here is a sample example in Java.

The table name is sample whose schema is defined as :

```
mysql> desc sample;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name  | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

A Java program to insert a row into the table will be as follows:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Dbconnectivity {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
        Connection myconn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/test","root","password");
        Statement st = myconn.createStatement();
        String query = "insert into test.sample values('random')";
        int x = st.executeUpdate(query);
        System.out.println("Number of records inserted : "+x);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Here in the code, the variable x holds the number of records inserted into the table.

For dynamic insertion, you can use the same code and find the cumulative sum if required.